# Django Python Key Error that I haven't been able to fix for 5 hours

Tags: python, django, session

I'm trying to route my login-page to a dashboard and for some reason my sessions aren't being read and I keep getting a key error that I can't seem to fix.

This is my views.py file and this is the error

'user_login': User.objects.get(id=request.session['user_id']),

```
def login(request):
    login_user = User.objects.filter(email=request.POST['email']), 
    request.session['user_id'] = login_user.id
    return redirect('/dashboard')

def dashboard(request):
    context = {
        'user_login': User.objects.get(id=request.session['user_id']),
        'user_quotes': Quote.objects.all().order_by('-created_at'),
    }
    return render(redirect, 'exam_app/dashboard.html', context)
```

Comment: can you post the full stack trace of the error please?

Comment: User.objects.filter(email=request.POST['email']).first()

Comment: good spot on that, although it's better to use `.get` if you're sure there is exactly one matching record (that returns the object directly, rather than a QuerySet)

Comment: Don't do this anyway. Django has an authentication framework; you should use that.

Answer (score 0):

when you use filter,you get back a queryset , If you want to get as single object, use either,

```
 login_user = User.objects.filter(email=request.POST['email']).first()
```

or

```
login_user = User.objects.get(email=request.POST['email'])
```